# Is it possible to insert arguments into functions when they're used like Function@ or //Function?

Tags: functions, syntax

Is it possible to insert arguments into functions when they're used like Function@ or //Function? Sometimes I need to do this, but then I have to return to the standard function usage: Function[]

Imagine I have this:

```
Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}]//TableForm
```

Or this:

```
TableForm@Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}]
```

But I don't like the default alignment and I want to use another alignment, say right. Will I always have to transform the above function into this:

```
TableForm[Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}], TableAlignments -> Right]
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this:

```
args = {1, 2, 3};

func @@ args

args // func@@#&
```

Or even:

```
args /. {x__} :> func[x]
```

---

Since it appears Brett better understood your original question I'll try to save this answer by giving a variation of the last one above:

```
Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}] /. x_ :> TableForm[x, TableAlignments -> Right]
```

Of course this is probably better:

```
Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}] // (TableForm[#, TableAlignments -> Right] &)
```

---

Taking this in a different direction, if you have a function like `TableForm` that you often want to use in this fashion, let me suggest an alternative:

```
myTable[opts___][tab_] := TableForm[tab, opts]
```

Now:

```
myTable[TableAlignments -> Right] @ Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}]
```

or:

```
Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}] // myTable[TableAlignments -> Right]
```

This approach could also be used for generic functions but the syntax may become unwieldy:

```
SetAttributes[addArgs, HoldAll]

addArgs[func_, args___] := Function[, func[#, args], HoldFirst]

Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}] // addArgs[TableForm, TableAlignments -> Right]
```

Comment: Of course the last one could be written as `Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}] // TableForm ~addOpts~ (TableAlignments -> Right)`

Answer (score 17):

Some possibilities:

```
In[15]:= a // f[#, 2] &
Out[15]= f[a, 2]

In[16]:= f[#, 2]& @ a
Out[16]= f[a, 2]

In[17]:= #~f~2& @ a    
Out[17]= f[a, 2]

In[18]:= a // #~f~2 &    
Out[18]= f[a, 2]
```

although you tend to lose legibility.

Answer (score 9):

If you go for infix, just be careful with the parentheses

```
Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}]~TableForm~(TableAlignments -> Right)
```

In these particular cases, it's good to remember that options can also be input as lists, so you could also do

```
Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}]~TableForm~{TableAlignments -> Right, TableDirections -> Row}
```

Comment: Making papa proud. ;^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, father's day in here ;)

Comment: Damn! While reading the answer I was sure I recognized the author.

Comment: Joy! SoftmaxLayer[][{1, 3, 2}]~NumberForm~2

Answer (score 4):

Since it's options you need to modify, why don't you just use [SetOptions](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetOptions.html) to do what you need?
This will make the default table alignment to the right

> ```
> SetOptions[TableForm,TableAlignments -> Right]
> ```

Then just use TableForm in any form you like. It will have the desired option set.

```
Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}]//TableForm
```

or

```
TableForm@Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}]
```

Or even

```
TableForm[Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since it hasn't been explicitly stated yet I'll add also this variant, which just defines a custom TableForm which then will enable one to use it in the convenient postfix form. Namely,

```
Clear[myTab];
myTab[table_List] := TableForm[table, TableAlignments -> Right];
Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}] // myTab
```

gives you the required structure. The same with #& notation:

```
Table[8^m - 1, {m, 1, 20}] // TableForm[#, TableAlignments -> Right] &
```