# Incorporating Built-In Function Options/Parameters into Shorthand

Tags: functions, syntax

Shorthand syntax provides an alternate way to apply functions and, in many cases, improves readability.  A simple example would be

```
 In[1]:=  numList = {1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1};
 In[2]:=  FromDigits@numList
Out[2]:=  1011011
```

instead of

```
 In[3]:=  FromDigits[numList]
Out[3]:=  1011011
```

Here, the syntax is simply `<function> @ <argument>`.  (There is also the weaker suffix `<argument> // <function>`.)  For lists, more sophisticated [methods of applying functions](https://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/guide/ApplyingFunctionsToLists.html) exist (`Map`, `Apply`, etc), some with their own shorthands (`/@`, `@@`).

Many built-in functions accept parameters and options in addition to arguments.  For example, one can specify which base to use for `FromDigits`:

```
 In[4]:=  FromDigits[numList, 2]
Out[4]:=  91
```

How do you incorporate function parameters/options into shorthand syntax?

EDIT:  After more searching of *Mathematica Stack Exchange*, I found [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6956/11627) by Brett Champion to [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6955/11627).  I believe it answers my question.

Comment: @Sektor Yep, I included it in my edit when I found it.  What's the SE policy here?  Should I go ahead and delete this question?

Comment: If you wish, but I think the more appropriate thing to do is leave it so It can be locked - this way even though it is locked new users will find what they are looking for easily :)