# How do you add options to a function that is being mapped?

Tags: list-manipulation, options, map

Simple example:

Normally: `ListPlot[list, Joined->True]`

If I want to map `ListPlot` how do I keep the `Joined` option?

thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply do `ListPlot[#, Joined -> True] & /@ {list1, list2}`?

Comment: Thanks, I am new at Mathematica. I apologize.

Comment: @Öskå It is indeed very basic, but maybe we should keep it.  Other beginners could likely search for the very same problem.  The title is descriptive.  You could post an answer.

Comment: `ListPlot` with option `Joined -> True` is probably not the best example here, since `ListLinePlot` would seem to render the option superfluous.

Comment: Somewhat related: [(6955)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6955) and [(29503)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29523)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you consider the following lists:

```
SeedRandom@1; list1 = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 2}];
SeedRandom@2; list2 = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 2}];
```

One can easily `Map` `ListPlot` by doing:

```
Map[ListPlot, {list1, list2}]
(* eq. to: ListPlot /@ {list1, list2} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you want to use `Options` with the `ListPlot` you need to define a function with the options in place. You can use either a conventional pattern-based function:

```
lp[x_] := ListPlot[x, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]
```

or you could use a [pure function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/25616#25616):

```
lp = ListPlot[#, Joined -> True, PlotMarkers -> Automatic]&
```

Then you can use it as follows:

```
Map[lp, {list1, list2}]
(* eq. to: lp /@ {list1, list2} *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Of course, it can still be used without `Map`:

```
lp[{list1, list2}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I edited this answer slightly as I felt it was misleading to say that you **need** to use a pure function.

Comment: That's right thanks :)